# Notebook with NVIDIA Optimus not switching video card in games

Tags: performance, optimus

I have a Samsung RC720 notebook with Intel Integrated Graphics and NVIDIA GeForce GT 520M.
As you can see it has two video adapters and Optimus is supposed to switch between them. But when I choose dedicated GPU in NVIDIA Control Panel and try to run, for example, GTA IV, it uses integrated graphics and I get very poor performance.

I have already installed last NVIDIA and notebook drivers, chose high-performance in NVIDIA Control Panel, tried to execute with "Run with graphics processor..." context option and so on.
Thanks for help.

Answer (score 1):

Download and use the latest drivers from the notebook manufacturer website, both Intel first and the Nvidia.  Once installed, download the latest driver from Nvidia.  Start the program and after it does the compatibility check, cancel the installer.  Click start, right click "My Computer" and select properties.

In the popup window on the top left side, click device manager.  In this popup window, find your Nvidia under "Display Adapters", and select update driver software.  Select "Let me pick", have disk and then browse to the unpacked Nvidia folder which is by default C:/Nvidia and continue in until you get to Display driver.  It will find the .inf itself and select open.  When it reloads back to the screen where your driver is listed click to install and allow it to finish.

Reboot and your Nvidia works with the latest Video driver.  Unfortunately, there is no way to update the Optimus controller and it still work and if you update the Intel video driver from Intel it will break as well.

The older Optimus controller with the latest Nvidia video driver works fine with all of the benefit of the new display driver and it does not matter that you have older Intel video driver as it will default to Nvidia anyways with the higher performance need.

OH!  Do *not* update the physX system software as it will break the Optimus also!

Answer (score 0):

My laptop has the same issue (Samsung NP300E5x-S01IN). In my case problem was with the BIOS. My BIOS version is p04RAC. Updated it to p07Rac and Geforce 610m got detected in windows 8.1.

But the update also changed my SATA controller from SATA 3 to SATA 2.

Answer (score 0):

I assumed you are using Windows 10.

According to [this page from NVIDIA](https://nvidia.custhelp.com/app/answers/detail/a_id/5035/%7E/run-with-graphics-processor-missing-from-context-menu%3A-change-in-process-of), beginning with the Windows 10 May 2020 Update (20H1), the method of setting the default video card changes.

Configurations are moved to `Windows Settings -> System -> Display -> Graphics settings`.

Have a try if all the other approaches did not help you.

Answer (score -1):

Not sure, never had this problem before, but what happens if you disable your integrated GPU through device manager?

Comment: The screen blacks out completely.

Comment: Try to uninstall the integrated graphics driver and then next install the NVIDIA graphics driver, perhaps the integrated card be disabled and thus in turn enable the NVIDIA one.
Alternatively, you could try to modify the bios of a laptop to disable optimus.
Probably won't do anything but have you tried using the other VGA port?

Comment: No, uninstalling integrated card and installing nvidia card leads to a situation in which I only have small resolution screen and system always tries to use a card with no drivers.  
And there is no such option in bios.